# Robot Framework: assign variable with if-else statement

Tags: integration-testing, robotframework

I use latest Robot Framework. 
I need to assign a value to my variable depending on value of an argument. That's how it would be in JavaScript:

```
ITEM_SELECTOR = RECENT_ITEM_SELECTOR + (
    position === 'last' ? ':last-child' : ':nth-child' + '(' + position + ')'
)
```

This is how I try to write it in Robot Framework:

```
${ITEM_SELECTOR} =    Run Keyword If    ${position} == 'last'    ${RECENT_ITEM_SELECTOR}:last-child
...    ELSE    ${RECENT_ITEM_SELECTOR}:nth-child(${position})
```

but this way `${RECENT_ITEM_SELECTOR}:nth-child(${position})` is considered a keyword, not assigned to `ITEM_SELECTOR`.

Then I try to preprend it with `No Operation`, but then my return value is considered its argument and I get `Keyword 'BuiltIn.No Operation' expected 0 arguments, got 1.`

How can I write it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are calling [run keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If), you have to give it a keyword to run. You can use [set variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable) to make your code work:

```
${ITEM_SELECTOR} =    Run Keyword If    ${position} == 'last'
...  Set variable    ${RECENT_ITEM_SELECTOR}:last-child
...  ELSE    
...  Set variable    ${RECENT_ITEM_SELECTOR}:nth-child(${position})
```

However, you can also use [set variable if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If) for a slightly more compact and readable solution:

```
${ITEM_SELECTOR} =    Set variable if    ${position} == 'last'
...  ${RECENT_ITEM_SELECTOR}:last-child
...  ${RECENT_ITEM_SELECTOR}:nth-child(${position})
```

Comment: Second option is much more readable.